# How I can get memberId for Provider.of

Tags: flutter, dart

Heloo everybody. I want to ask you, how i can delete my ListView item,and send this to the Provider.of<Members>(context)

I used to try many variants of changing. But in some case i get 'a dismissed dismissible widget is still part of the tree' error. In another after restate my ListView stay without change.
I understan that problem  is Provide to 'void removeMember' member id.

GitHub url
https://github.com/Rodion98/wor_app.git

Comment: its better to put the code here, instead of github repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your delete item logic is wrong, just try this

```
void removeMember(String memberId) {
    _items.remove(_items.firstWhere((element) => element.idl == memberId));
    notifyListeners();
  }
```